# Why mysqli executed prepared statement is not saving?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've just learning to use prepared statement in mysqli & php. Here's the snippet of the code in question.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare ("UPDATE courses set id=?, title=?, description=?, videourl=?, article=?, colcount=?, questiondisplayed=?, onfield=? WHERE id = ?");
if ($stmt == false) { die ('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error)); }
$res = $stmt->bind_param("sssssiiis", $id, $title, $description2, $videourl, $article2, $colcount, $questiondisplayed, $onfield, $oldid);
if ($res == false) { die ('bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error)); }
$res = $stmt->execute();
if ($res == false) die ('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
```

The problem is, even after these codes run successfully (the die function never gets called), the database is not updated at all. But it's updated successfully if I'm not using prepared statement (construct the SQL query string manually). I want to convert from using manually constructed SQL query string into prepared statement. But I'm stuck in this area. Btw, the variables supplied in bind param have been set right before these codes run. I've run a `print_r ($_POST);` and it shows that my POST values are contain the right data. Where's the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried checking the number of affected rows after the execute? It could succeed, meaning the query was valid, but not have found any rows to change. Use `$stmt->affected_rows`

Comment: According to the docs that shouldn't be necessary @Mihai

Comment: Also, what is the datatype of the id column? You have it typed as a string, I'm not sure how that will work if it is actually an integer.

Comment: @all: sorry, it was a silly me. I have just recently add a check for duplicate primary key, which of course will return true because I'm going to update an existing key (id). So the code wasn't even run at all. But now it's run, it raises error `bind_param() failed: Duplicate entry 'S101' for key 'PRIMARY'`. I'm still investigate it, but if I will ask question about it, I guess it will be for entirely another question. but this can be discovered because @Evan OJack gives idea about $stmt->affected_rows, which in turns makes me questioning whether all these codes were run at all. Thanks!

Comment: All is well now! Thanks!